# changing color in pdfBox has no effect while working with form fields

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a pdf with some form fields that I want to fill. I am using Java and pdfBox v2.0.27.

everything works as expected but I cannot figure out how to change the color of the text that I am writing.

here is what I am doing:

1. I get the form from the pdf:

```
            PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("./assets/prostateTemplate.pdf"));
            PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
```

2. I change the font and the color (font changes, color does not):

```
                PDFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
                PDResources resources = new PDResources();
                resources.put(COSName.HELV, font);
    
                pDAcroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);
    
                String defaultAppearanceString = "/Helv 0 Tf 1 g";
                pDAcroForm.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);
```

3. then I loop over the fields and set ther values:

```
        PDField field = pDAcroForm.getField(fieldID);
        if(field != null){
            field.setValue(replacementText);

        }
```

this line `"/Helv 0 Tf 1 g"` is supposed to change the color of the text. `1 g` should produce white text. I have also tried `"/Helv 0 Tf 1 1 1 rg"` and `"/Helv 0 Tf 1 1 1 rgb"` to no effect.

### what I get

I get the correct text with the correct font written on the doc but the color is black

### what I want

I want to change the color to white

for reference, here is the entire code in one block:

```
package com.giacom;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PdfBoy {
    private static Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            data = PatientData.loadData("./assets/prostateData.xlsx");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("there is no such file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PdfBoy.createProstatePDF();
    }

    public static void createProstatePDF(){
        try {

            System.out.println("working on your prostate report...");
            PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("./assets/prostateTemplate.pdf"));
            PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

            // Set the font for form fields
//            PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(pDDocument, new File("./assets/times.ttf"));
            PDFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
            PDResources resources = new PDResources();
            resources.put(COSName.HELV, font);

            pDAcroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);

            // Acrobat sets the font size on the form level to be
            // auto sized as default. This is done by setting the font size to '0'
            String defaultAppearanceString = "/Helv 0 Tf 1 g";
            pDAcroForm.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);


            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue();
//                System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);
                if(key != null && value != null) {
                    replaceFormField(pDAcroForm, key, value);
                }
            }

            PDPage page = pDDocument.getPage(0);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pDDocument, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);

            addCircleToPdf(contentStream, Color.ORANGE, 100, 190);



            contentStream.close();


            pDDocument.save("./outputs/prostateReport.pdf");
            pDDocument.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("there is no such file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void createChestPDF(){
        try {

            System.out.println("working on your chest report...");
            PDDocument pDDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("./assets/chestTemplate.pdf"));
            PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = pDDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();


            replaceFormField(pDAcroForm, "PATIENT_ID", "chest report");

            PDPage page = pDDocument.getPage(0);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pDDocument, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);

            addCircleToPdf(contentStream, Color.ORANGE, 100, 190);



            contentStream.close();


            pDDocument.save("./outputs/chestReport.pdf");
            pDDocument.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void replaceFormField(PDAcroForm pDAcroForm, String fieldID, String replacementText) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(pDAcroForm.getDefaultAppearance());
        PDField field = pDAcroForm.getField(fieldID);
//        System.out.println(fieldID + " -> " + field);
        if(field != null){
//            System.out.println("replacement text " + replacementText);
            System.out.println(field);
            field.setValue(replacementText);

        }
    }


    private static void addCircleToPdf(PDPageContentStream contentStream, Color color, int positionX, int positionY) throws IOException {
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(color);
        createCircleUsingCurves(contentStream, positionX, positionY, 5);
        contentStream.fill();
    }

    private static void createCircleUsingCurves(PDPageContentStream contentStream, float x, float y, float radius) throws IOException {
        contentStream.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        contentStream.curveTo(x + radius, y + radius * 0.5523f,
                x + radius * 0.5523f, y + radius,
                x, y + radius);
        contentStream.curveTo(x - radius * 0.5523f, y + radius,
                x - radius, y + radius * 0.5523f,
                x - radius, y);
        contentStream.curveTo(x - radius, y - radius * 0.5523f,
                x - radius * 0.5523f, y - radius,
                x, y - radius);
        contentStream.curveTo(x + radius * 0.5523f, y - radius,
                x + radius, y - radius * 0.5523f,
                x + radius, y);
        contentStream.closePath();
    }
}
```

here is the content of the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.giacom</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdf-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>pdf-java</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dhatim</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastexcel-reader</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dhatim</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastexcel</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: @KJ the pdf has a dark background so I need the text to be white :D

Comment: I see. I have a very specific use case here where I am using a pdf inside a dicom file. the pdf is a medical report that will be displayed on a medical image viewer which has a dark theme, that is why I chose a dark pdf background.

Comment: Can you share the result PDF? Your code looks correct.

Comment: You set the default appearance for the form in general. If the fields in question do have their own default appearance values, the form-wide value will be ignored. Thus, have you tried setting the field default appearance values?

Comment: @mkl I tried to set the style on the field but i could not figure out how. there is no method to change the style on a PDField object https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/PDField.html

Comment: @TilmanHausherr here is the output pdf https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DvHBQ4YS7gFC_8wq6nFgwCZOfBI6u3TH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah mkl is right. Call `setDefaultAppearance` for each field if it is of type `PDVariableText`. See also the `CreateSimpleForm` example in the example subproject in the source code download. Btw I after writing this I tried ChatGPT and it brings a similar answer, wow.

Comment: @Hasan *"I tried to set the style on the field but i could not figure out how."* - As a _default appearance_ only makes sense for text fields, the `setDefaultAppearance` method is not in `PDField` but only in `PDVariableText`, compare Tilman's comment.

Comment: I've added an answer. I didn't test it, so please comment if it doesn't work 

Answer (score 1):

I was unsure if it was practical to invert Form Field colours.

I can say it should be possible with a library like PDFbox however the quandary remains that its not a good practical use to reverse from a normal rendering since in the De Facto Viewer Adobe Acrobat, seen here in middle left (which others "should" for compliance emulate) the data is very washed out. Also on occasion the data does not always appear.

[image]

So the object needs to be somthing like

```
6 0 obj
<</AP<</N 11 0 R>>/DA(1 1 1 rg /Helv 0 Tf)/F 4/FT/Tx/M(D:20230610000000+00'00')/MK<</BC[1 1 1]/BG[0 0 0]>>/P 7 0 R/Rect[180.081 700.364 291.329 722.364]/Subtype/Widget/T(Text1)/Type/Annot/V(Hello Dark World !)>>
endobj
```

Where background is clearly black and annotation text appearance is white
and you can set border colour either way as desired.

It took several attempts to get it to "stick" in my manual attempts, and apparently that has been an issue in the past with PDFBox (which I do not use). Thus I suggest ensure your using most recent version with recent acroform changes <strike>and review any residual problem at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5614?jql=project%20%3D%20PDFBOX%20AND%20component%20%3D%20AcroForm</strike> 
Reportedly will be fixed in next version. 2.0.29 / 3.0

Comment: great work. will test it out when I get some time. thanks for your time. it was a pleasure communicating with you.

Answer (score 1):

change your segment (3) into this:

```
PDField field = pDAcroForm.getField(fieldID);
if (field instanceof PDVariableText)
{
    ((PDVariableText) field).setDefaultAppearance("/Helv 0 Tf 1 g");
    field.setValue(replacementText);
}
```